# Regexp : repeat matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to create a regular expression that can contain some of those three elements 0...X times :

**/cat1/var1**

**/cat2/var2**

**/cat3/var3**

This is what I got so far :

```
((cat1|cat2|cat3)/(?P<var>\w+))*
```

In this sample string it's only matching the first occurrence : **http://url.dev/cat1/aaaaa**/cat1/bbbbb/cat2/ccccc

In this sample there is also two occurrences of cat1, I would like to know if its possible to harvest the two values.

A few samples of what I want to match :

**http://url.dev/cat1/aaaaa/cat1/bbbbb/cat2/ccccc/cat3/ddddd/cat3/eeeee**

**http://url.dev/cat1/aaaaa**

**http://url.dev/cat2/aaaaa/cat3/bbbbb**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you just use

```
(cat\d/(?P<var\d>\w+))*
```

It will match all cat/var occurences

[EDIT]

so was :

```
/(cat\d\/\w+)/g
```

Comment: Maybe you wan't to keep the value of "the int"? if not try simpler http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31g3o